# Vuforia iOS SDK : Combine ImageTargets & VideoPlayback example

Tags: ios, vuforia

I'm developing an iOS app using Vuforia iOS SDK (not the unity plugin).

I want to mix the `VideoPlayback` and `ImageTargets` sample together. From the forum suggestion I started with the videoplayback sample and integrate imageTarget on it. After editing the EAGLView files the app gets both video and 3D model but **doesn't show the 3D model**. When the image is tracked, it gets the 3D object inside `renderFrameQCAR` and prints log.

I can't understand where to look at. Has anyone tried and done this without Unity support? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you found the solution ? I am facing the same problem..

Comment: yup i'm posting an answer

Comment: I'm looking for the solution which can apply for Sample Version 2.6.6

Comment: they have completely changed the objects3d…. its now called VuforiaObject3D

Comment: thanks good to know, i guess it will be less complicated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start working on VideoPlayback project,change only in the `EAGLView` files for sample import the `Teapot.h` file in `EAGLview.m`

add code parts from `ImageTargets` the top within the namespace declaration:

```
const float kObjectScale = 3.0f;
const char* textureFilenames[] = {
    "icon_play.png",
    "icon_loading.png",
    "icon_error.png",
    "VuforiaSizzleReel_1.png",
    "VuforiaSizzleReel_2.png",

    // added for 3d model
    "TextureTeapotBrass.png",
    "TextureTeapotBlue.png",
    "TextureTeapotRed.png"
};
```

add this function (from `ImageTargets`)

```
- (void)setup3dObjects
{
for (int i=0; i < [textures count]; ++i) {
    Object3D* obj3D = [[Object3D alloc] init];
    if (i >= 5)
    {
        obj3D.numVertices = NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_VERTEX;
        obj3D.vertices = teapotVertices;
        obj3D.normals = teapotNormals;
        obj3D.texCoords = teapotTexCoords;
        obj3D.numIndices = NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX;
        obj3D.indices = teapotIndices;
    }
    obj3D.texture = [textures objectAtIndex:i];
    [objects3D addObject:obj3D];
    [obj3D release];
}
}
```

Then, in the `RenderFrameQCAR`, after:

```
int numActiveTrackables = state.getNumTrackableResults();
```

add codes for 3d model, comes from `ImageTargets` sample

```
for (int i = 0; i < state.getNumTrackableResults(); ++i) {
    // Get the trackable
    const QCAR::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
    const QCAR::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();
    QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

    // Choose the texture based on the target name
    int targetIndex = 0; // "stones"
    if (!strcmp(trackable.getName(), "chips"))
        targetIndex = 1;
    else if (!strcmp(trackable.getName(), "tarmac"))
        targetIndex = 2;
    Object3D *obj3D = [objects3D objectAtIndex:targetIndex+5];

    // OpenGL 2
    QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;
    ShaderUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, kObjectScale, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
    ShaderUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScale, kObjectScale, kObjectScale, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
    ShaderUtils::multiplyMatrix(&qUtils.projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.normals);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.texCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [obj3D.texture textureID]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
    glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, obj3D.numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.indices);
    ShaderUtils::checkGlError("EAGLView renderFrameQCAR");
}
```

just ensure all your stuff loaded correctly, should work just fine.

Comment: **Notice:** This does not apply for samples version 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on real experience.

I call the 3d model in the videoplayback call, i mean like this

```
if (strcmp(imageTarget.getName(), "affogato") == 0)
{
const int kObjectScale = 500;
[self secondSetup3dObjects];
playerIndex = 99;
const QCAR::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());
int targetIndex = 9;
Object3D *obj3D = [objects3D objectAtIndex:targetIndex];
QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;
ShaderUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
ShaderUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScale, kObjectScale, kObjectScale, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
ShaderUtils::multiplyMatrix(&qUtils.projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);
glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.normals);
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.texCoords);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [obj3D.texture textureID]);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
            glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,  obj3D.numVertices);

            ShaderUtils::checkGlError("EAGLView renderFrameQCAR");
```

I hope this can help anyone...

Oh, BTW you need to put in the appdelegate a video to this target and a transparent Background to the texture to make this work like a charm
Regards